# Phusion Passenger is currently not serving any applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger

I got error like `Phusion Passenger is currently not serving any applications.`
 while trying to restart passenger with `passenger-config restart-app` command.

I googled but most of the answers were only related with deployment.

I want to restart passenger in the development environment  as I am using vhost. 
PS. My web server is nginx.

Comment: Did your (re-)start your app with `touch app-directory/current/tmp/restart.txt`?

Comment: @sugaryourcoffee, yes I have, but it is also not restarting my app.

Comment: What does `passenger-config validate-install` and `passenger-status` say?

Comment: @sugaryourcoffee, can u turn your comment into answer.

Comment: do you need more information or what do you mean with 'turn comment into an answer'

Comment: @sugaryourcoffee, no , your comment worked fine. I made a mistake with restart.txt name.

Comment: @sugaryourcoffee You made a good comment wich turn out to resolves his problem. He wants you to answer through the answer box so he van check the problem as resolved with your answer.

Comment: Has anyone found a solution for this as yet? I have my application running with passenger [here](http://clashere.com:3000) but when I run `passenger-status <instance>` I get **Phusion Passenger is currently not serving any applications**.

Comment: Additionally, when I run my node app like this in passenger:
`passenger start --app-type node --startup-file myapp.js`
I can see my that my app is being served, but `passenger-status` still says that it's not serving my application.

Answer (score 11):

See my comment [here](https://github.com/phusion/passenger-docker/issues/137#issuecomment-287410836).

You need to explicitly specify, where actual Ruby code of a Rails application is located, using `passenger_app_root` directive, described in [Passenger's documentaion](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#passenger_app_root).

Without this directive, Passenger will thinck, that actual Ruby code is located in path, specified with root nginx-directive.

Example of a correct configuration file '/etc/nginx/sites-available/app_name':

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name 188.225.35.216;
  passenger_enabled on;
  rails_env    production;
  root         /path/to/your/app/public/folder;
  passenger_app_root /path/to/your/app/code; # <<< Point Passenger to application code

  # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root   html;
  }
}
```

In my case, Passenger was't serving my Rails app, that was deployed with Capistrano.
I had have to specify a value for `passenger_app_root` like following `/var/www/my_app/current`.

This will point Passenger exactly, where application code is presented.

Answer (score 4):

I am betting your passenger is running.
If you look at step 3, it hints at what I am talking about.

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/trusty/

Nginx will take care of passenger for you if it's set up to do that.
Can you try the command in that tutorial and look for passenger processes too ?

```
sudo /usr/sbin/passenger-memory-stats
```

Good luck!